# Prove an algorithm which takes (n+1)^5 steps is O(n^5)?

Tags: algorithm, performance, analysis, processing-efficiency

Find out the c and n0. 
Please explain with the steps.

Comment: Forget about the algorithm. It's a question of how it can be proved mathematically.

Comment: If the time taken is proportional to (n+1)⁵, then it's O(n⁵) by definition. What's to prove?

Comment: Expand (n+1)^5 and your answer falls out easily.

Comment: I need the value of c & n0

Comment: @vengets: There are many ways to do this, and no correct way, so I don't think it's a very good fit. Also you don't explain what c and n0 are. Not everyone uses the same letters, so how do you expect people to know what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

limit as n --> infinity of (n+1)^5 / n^5 = 1.

This is neither 0 nor infinity, so they have the same complexity.  This complexity is traditionally written as O(n^5).

This does assume that each step is constant for whatever you are measuring.

Comment: Need c value & n. value pls

Comment: OP, note that this holds for any value of *c* and *n*. Pick a number, any number.